# windows service run at exactly 11:59:59 PM

Tags: datetime, timer, windows-services

I am Writing a Windows service which will export reports to excel at user defined time. The User can choose to run report with following options:

1. By Selecting StartTime and EndTime with DailyTime as the time to generate report
2. Daily Report
3. Weekly Report
4. Monthly Report
5. Yearly Report.

Note( My SQL Server Data is Updated every second & I have written a Windows Application From which user will configure the above, which will be saved to xml)

My windows service to configured to run at TimerInterval of 30000.

My problems are:
1. if User sets Start Time of 10:00 PM and End Time as 12:00 AM and dailytime as 12:00AM my below code fails as i am using system.datetime.now

```
 DateTime tempDailyTime=DateTime.ParseExact(DailyTime,"HH:mm:ss tt",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                    string curTime = System.DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss tt");
                    DateTime tempCurrentTime = DateTime.ParseExact(curTime, "HH:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                    if (tempCurrentTime >= tempDailyTime)
                    {

                        string tempFilename=Convert.ToString(tempDailyTime.TimeOfDay).Replace(":","-")+".xlsx";
                        if (!File.Exists(tempDir + "\\DailyTime" + "\\" + ReportName + "_" + tempFilename))
                        {
                            GenerateReportWithStartTimeandEndTime(ReportName,ReportID,ConnectionString,ReportColumnName,ReportBQuery,StartTime,EndTime,DailyTime,tempDir+"\\DailyTime",tempFilename);
                        }
                    }
```

2. For Generating Daily,Weekly,Monthly,Yearly I have specified the scheduled time to run the report as

   DateTime scheduleTime = new DateTime(currentTime.Year, currentTime.Month, currentTime.Day, 23, 59, 59, 999);

after the timer elapse before reaching the below code part if datetime changes it will generate a blank report.
My Daily Report Generation code is below:

```
 if (Daily == "true")
                    {
                        DateTime currentTime = DateTime.Now;
                        int intervalToElapse = 0;
                        DateTime scheduleTime = new DateTime(currentTime.Year, currentTime.Month, currentTime.Day, 23, 59, 59, 999);

                        if (currentTime <= scheduleTime)
                            intervalToElapse = (int)scheduleTime.Subtract(currentTime).TotalSeconds;
                        else
                            intervalToElapse = (int)scheduleTime.AddDays(1).Subtract(currentTime).TotalSeconds;

                        _DailyTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(intervalToElapse);
                        if (_DailyTimer.Interval == 0)
                        {
                            //GenerateDailyReport(ReportName, ReportID, ConnectionString, ReportColumnName, ReportBQuery, StartTime, EndTime, DailyTime, tempDir + "\\DailyTime", tempFilename);
                        }

                    }
                    if (Weekly == "true")
                    {
                        //GenerateWeeklyReport(ReportName, ReportID, ConnectionString, ReportColumnName, ReportBQuery, StartTime, EndTime, DailyTime, tempDir + "\\DailyTime", tempFilename);
                    }
                    if (Monthly == "true")
                    {
                        //GenerateMonthlyReport(ReportName, ReportID, ConnectionString, ReportColumnName, ReportBQuery, StartTime, EndTime, DailyTime, tempDir + "\\DailyTime", tempFilename);
                    }
                    if (Yearly == "true")
                    {
                        //GenerateYearlyReport(ReportName, ReportID, ConnectionString, ReportColumnName, ReportBQuery, StartTime, EndTime, DailyTime, tempDir + "\\DailyTime", tempFilename);
                    }
```

The data to generate report is coming from xml File below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ArrayOfAutoReportXML>
  <AutoReportXML ReportName="oks" ReportID="64" ConnectionString="server='KHASIM-PC\SQLEXPRESS';uid='sa';pwd='khasim123';database='ReportMgr'" ReportBQuery="SELECT t1.id, t1.pt100, t1.pt200, t1.pt300, t1.inverter1, t1.voltage1, t1.power1, t1.inverter2, t1.voltage2, t1.power2, t1.cdt  FROM ab_Test t1 WHERE  t1.cdt BETWEEN @VALUE1 and @VALUE2" ReportColumnName="cdt" StartTime="18:00:00 PM" EndTime="22:00:00 PM" DailyTime="22:01:00 PM" Daily="true" Weekly="true" Monthly="true" Yearly="true" Loc="C:\Users\khasim\Desktop\testAutoGenerated" />
  <AutoReportXML ReportName="ShiftC" ReportID="63" ConnectionString="server='KHASIM-PC\SQLEXPRESS';uid='sa';pwd='khasim123';database='ReportMgr'" ReportBQuery="SELECT t1.id, t1.pt100, t1.pt200, t1.pt300, t1.inverter1, t1.voltage1, t1.power1, t1.inverter2, t1.voltage2, t1.power2, t1.cdt  FROM ab_Test t1 WHERE  t1.cdt BETWEEN @VALUE1 and @VALUE2" ReportColumnName="cdt" StartTime="22:00:00 PM" EndTime="06:00:00 AM" DailyTime="18:01:00 PM" Daily="true" Weekly="true" Monthly="true" Yearly="true" Loc="C:\Users\khasim\Desktop\testAutoGenerated" />
  <AutoReportXML ReportName="ShiftB" ReportID="62" ConnectionString="server='KHASIM-PC\SQLEXPRESS';uid='sa';pwd='khasim123';database='ReportMgr'" ReportBQuery="SELECT t1.id, t1.pt100, t1.pt200, t1.pt300, t1.inverter1, t1.voltage1, t1.power1, t1.inverter2, t1.voltage2, t1.power2, t1.cdt  FROM ab_Test t1 WHERE  t1.cdt BETWEEN @VALUE1 and @VALUE2" ReportColumnName="cdt" StartTime="14:00:00 PM" EndTime="22:00:00 PM" DailyTime="22:01:00 PM" Daily="true" Weekly="true" Monthly="true" Yearly="true" Loc="C:\Users\khasim\Desktop\testAutoGenerated" />
  <AutoReportXML ReportName="shiftA" ReportID="61" ConnectionString="server='KHASIM-PC\SQLEXPRESS';uid='sa';pwd='khasim123';database='ReportMgr'" ReportBQuery="SELECT t1.id, t1.pt100, t1.pt200, t1.pt300, t1.inverter1, t1.voltage1, t1.power1, t1.inverter2, t1.voltage2, t1.power2, t1.cdt  FROM ab_Test t1 WHERE  t1.cdt BETWEEN @VALUE1 and @VALUE2" ReportColumnName="cdt" StartTime="06:00:00 AM" EndTime="14:00:00 PM" DailyTime="14:01:00 PM" Daily="true" Weekly="true" Monthly="true" Yearly="true" Loc="C:\Users\khasim\Desktop\testAutoGenerated" />
  <AutoReportXML ReportName="testreport1" ReportID="59" ConnectionString="server='KHASIM-PC\SQLEXPRESS';uid='sa';pwd='khasim123';database='ReportMgr'" ReportBQuery="SELECT t0.testid, t0.pt500, t0.pt600, t0.cdt  FROM sampletest t0 WHERE  t0.cdt BETWEEN @VALUE1 and @VALUE2" ReportColumnName="cdt" StartTime="17:00:00 PM" EndTime="11:59:59 PM" DailyTime="00:01:00 AM" Daily="true" Weekly="true" Monthly="true" Yearly="true" Loc="C:\Users\khasim\Desktop\testAutoGenerated" />
  <AutoReportXML ReportName="testreport" ReportID="58" ConnectionString="server='KHASIM-PC\SQLEXPRESS';uid='sa';pwd='khasim123';database='ReportMgr'" ReportBQuery="SELECT t0.testid, t0.pt500, t0.pt600, t0.cdt  FROM sampletest t0 WHERE  t0.cdt BETWEEN @VALUE1 and @VALUE2" ReportColumnName="cdt" StartTime="09:00:00 AM" EndTime="17:00:00 PM" DailyTime="17:01:00 PM" Daily="true" Weekly="true" Monthly="true" Yearly="true" Loc="C:\Users\khasim\Desktop\testAutoGenerated" />
  <AutoReportXML ReportName="somereport" ReportID="57" ConnectionString="server='KHASIM-PC\SQLEXPRESS';uid='sa';pwd='khasim123';database='ReportMgr'" ReportBQuery="SELECT t0.testid, t0.pt500, t0.pt600, t0.cdt  FROM sampletest t0 WHERE  t0.cdt BETWEEN @VALUE1 and @VALUE2" ReportColumnName="cdt" StartTime="02:00:00 AM" EndTime="05:37:47 AM" DailyTime="06:37:47 AM" Daily="True" Weekly="True" Monthly="True" Yearly="True" Loc="C:\Users\khasim\Desktop\testAutoGenerated">57</AutoReportXML>
</ArrayOfAutoReportXML>
```

I need suggestions how to handle this or what I am doing wrong.

Comment: This is not clear enough. What is the role of the timer here? If you want to execute a task at a particular time, you should set the timer interval to 1sec and keep monitoring system time until the system time reach the time that you want to execute your task.

Comment: my timer is set for 30 seconds. for every 30 seconds it will run the service and perform job. daily means every 24 hrs. weekly 7days monthly based on start and end of month, yearly mean start and end of year. i was considering intervaltoelapse in seconds and checking which was wrong instead i have added  private DateTime _lastRun = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1); and if (_lastRun.Date < DateTime.Now.Date)
    { //GenerateDailyReport with starttime as _lastrun.date and end time as datetime.now.date } similarly i need to do for weekly, monthly, yearly.

Comment: The above logic will not work in the long run. It will keep shifting the last run time. Which means you will not be able to start task at 12 midnight.

Comment: i can set _lastrun.date as starttime which is (29/02/2016 12:00:00AM) which is start of day and endtime as DateTime schTime = new DateTime(_lastRun.Year, _lastRun.Month, _lastRun.Day, 23, 59, 59, 999); which will give (29/02/2016 23:59:59.999) which is end of that particular day right..Then I will do GenerateReport(StartTime,EndTime); then i can get the data between these two  using sql eg: select * from sometable between starttime and endtime. what am i doing wrong. please give me some suggestions.

Comment: Your time can be 30 secs behind, because of your timer interval. So assume it checks last run date at 12.00.30AM. So the task will run because the last run date > 1 day. But for the current instance last run time would be 12.00.30AM. Similarly next day the timer will detect the task at 12:01:00AM. You will be able to minimize this issue by overriding last run time to 12:00:00AM.

Comment: i am just checking the date not time then assigning time for that _lastrundate to get the report once the report is generated i am updating the lastrundate to present date so it will run for next date change only can you check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35714505/running-windows-service-at-midnight/35715356#35715356

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104967/discussion-between-tan-and-kosala-w).