# running windows service at midnight

Tags: c#, datetime, windows-services

my code executes every 5 minutes, within the 5 minutes if date changes my code will not run. how to handle this, please help

I think i need to check currenttime.addminutes(5) and check if date
 changes and if date changes then need to set timer so that my code can
 run can any one help he how to implement this

```
 if (Daily == "true")//run daily at 11:59:59
     {
      DateTime currentTime = DateTime.Now;
      int intervalToElapse = 0;
      DateTime scheduleTime = new DateTime(currentTime.Year, currentTime.Month, currentTime.Day, 23, 59, 59, 999);

     if (currentTime <= scheduleTime)
   intervalToElapse = (int)scheduleTime.Subtract(currentTime).TotalSeconds;
                                    else
                                        intervalToElapse = (int)scheduleTime.AddDays(1).Subtract(currentTime).TotalSeconds;

                                    _DailyTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(intervalToElapse);
                                    if (_DailyTimer.Interval == 0)//if date changes this will be false and the code will not run
                                    {
                                        string tempFilename = Convert.ToString(tempDailyTime.TimeOfDay).Replace(":", "-") + ".xlsx";
                                        if (!File.Exists(tempDir + "\\Daily" + "\\" + ReportName + "_" + tempFilename))
                                        {
                                            GenerateDailyReport(ReportName, ReportID, ConnectionString, ReportColumnName, ReportBQuery, "00:00:00", "23:59:59", tempDir + "\\Daily", tempFilename);
                                        }
                                    }

                                }
```

Comment: Where is the "midnight" part ? and what is `Daily`?

Comment: daily is every 24 hrs, if (_DailyTimer.Interval == 0) seconds

Comment: i have posted my question clearly at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35704478/windows-service-run-at-exactly-115959-pm

Answer (score 0):

The Problem with my above code is that I was trying to check elapsed time and compare it to zero. Instead, if the date change is identified, and check it with the current date for date change which obviously means the time has elapsed so the code will run and create report successfully.

```
private DateTime _lastRun = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
    if (Daily == "true")
                            {
                                //DateTime currentTime = DateTime.Now;

                                //int intervalToElapse = 0;
                                //DateTime scheduleTime = new DateTime(currentTime.Year, currentTime.Month, currentTime.Day, 23, 59, 59, 999);

                                //if (currentTime <= scheduleTime)
                                //    intervalToElapse = (int)scheduleTime.Subtract(currentTime).TotalSeconds;
                                //else
                                //    intervalToElapse = (int)scheduleTime.AddDays(1).Subtract(currentTime).TotalSeconds;

                                //_DailyTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(intervalToElapse);
                                //if (_DailyTimer.Interval == 0)
                                //{
                                if (_lastRun.Date < DateTime.Now.Date)
                                {
                                    DateTime schTime = new DateTime(_lastRun.Year, _lastRun.Month, _lastRun.Day, 23, 59, 59, 999);
                                    string tempFilename = Convert.ToString(tempDailyTime.TimeOfDay).Replace(":", "-") + ".xlsx";
                                    if (!File.Exists(tempDir + "\\Daily" + "\\" + ReportName + "_" + tempFilename))
                                    {
                                        GenerateDailyReport(ReportName, ReportID, ConnectionString, ReportColumnName, ReportBQuery,Convert.ToString(_lastRun.Date), Convert.ToString(schTime), tempDir + "\\Daily", tempFilename);
_lastRun = DateTime.Now;
                                    }
                                }
                                //}

                            }
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is not your personal code pad. Answers without explanation will probably get deleted

Comment: sorry i was not aware of that. I have added explanation. thank you